# How to compile Microsoft Silverlight for Symbian as .SIS (stand alone) application?

Tags: c#, c++, silverlight, symbian

So in nokia  we can have sort of Microsoft Silverlight installed to system. We can see Silverlight apps in browser, interact with them.

But how to compile that silverlight application into .SIS applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/devices/symbian/
Sounds like it is still a beta, so you may try its beta forum where experts are available.